# Print details of an employee by entering the name of employee in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am getting input of details of the employee from the user and then asking the user to enter the name of the employee, he wants to retrieve information of. I am saving all the entered data in a dictionary with employee name as its key and [employee_id, salary, address] as the values. Now whatever name I enter to retrieve the details, the output is always the details of the last entered employee.

```
    n = int(input('Enter the number of employee: '))
    employees = {}
    
    for i in range(n):
        name = input('Enter the name of the employee: ')
        emp_id = input("Enter employee Id: ")
        sal = int(input("Enter the employee salary: "))
        address = input('Enter the employee address: ')
        employees[name] = [emp_id, sal, address]
    
    while True:
        name = input('Enter employee name: ')
        info = employees.get(name, -1)
        if info == -1:
            print('Employee does not exist')
        else:
            print('Employee details are: \n Employee Id: ', emp_id, '\n Salary: ', sal, '\n Address: ', address)
        
        exit_choice = input('Do you want to exit [Yes|No]: ')
        if exit_choice == 'No' or exit_choice == 'no':
            break
```

I want to get the output as the details of the employee whose name is entered. Please can you help me get out of this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lots of bug in your code, the correct code will be,

```
n = int(input('Enter the number of employee: '))
employees = {}
    
for i in range(n):
    name = input('Enter the name of the employee: ')
    emp_id = input("Enter employee Id: ")
    sal = int(input("Enter the employee salary: "))
    address = input('Enter the employee address: ')
    employees[name] = [emp_id, sal, address]

while True:
    name = input('Enter employee name: ')
    info = employees.get(name, -1)
    if info == -1:
        print('Employee does not exist')
    else:
        print(f'Employee details are: \n Employee Id: {info[0]}\n Salary: {info[1]}\n Address: info[2])')
    
    exit_choice = input('Do you want to exit [Yes|No]: ')
    if exit_choice == 'Yes' or exit_choice == 'yes':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing the information you got from the dictionary. You need to get that from `info`.

```
   while True:
        name = input('Enter employee name: ')
        info = employees.get(name, -1)
        if info == -1:
            print('Employee does not exist')
        else:
            emp_id sal, address = info
            print('Employee details are: \n Employee Id: ', emp_id, '\n Salary: ', sal, '\n Address: ', address)
        
        exit_choice = input('Do you want to exit [Yes|No]: ')
        if exit_choice == 'No' or exit_choice == 'no':
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
while True:
    name = input('Enter employee name: ')
    info = employees.get(name, -1)
    if info == -1:
        print('Employee does not exist')
    else:
        print(f'Employee details are: \n Employee Id: {info[0]} \n Salary: {info[1]} \n Address: {info[2]}')
    #And then the exit thing
```